# Clean code practice with RecyclerView ViewHolders that use same methods. Kotlin

Tags: android, kotlin, mvvm, android-recyclerview

so I have 3 viewholders in my recyclerview adapter that use the same methods.
I was wondering if there's a clean code practice to accommodate for all these viewholder types that use the same methods?

Obviously, I can't just create a class to hold the methods and extend, as the viewholders already need to extend "RecyclerView.ViewHolder(binding.root)" like so:

```
private inner class ViewHolder1(binding: ViewBinding) : RecyclerView.Viewholder(binding.root) {

 fun someMethod() {
 }
}

private inner class ViewHolder2(binding: View2Binding) : RecyclerView.Viewholder(binding.root) {

 fun someMethod() {
 }
}
```

How do I accommodate for this? I have multiple methods that are being re-used and yes I can put these methods outside into the entire adapter class, but I'm not sure if that's the cleanest way possible.. What do you guys think?

Comment: Common interface with the properties that the function uses. Define the function as an extension of the interface.

Comment: @Tenfour04 Yep makes sense, thanks!